# How to remove item from AsyncStorage before closing react native app

Tags: react-native

How I can remove item from AsyncStorage when I close react native app?.

app.js:

```js
state = {
    appState: AppState.currentState
}

componentDidMount() {
  AppState.addEventListener('change', this.handleAppStateChange);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  AppState.removeEventListener('change', this.handleAppStateChange);
}

handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState) => {
  if (this.state.appState.match(/inactive|background/) && nextAppState === 'active') {
   AsyncStorage.removeItem('item');
 console.log("App has come to the foreground!");
  }
this.setState({ appState: nextAppState });    
}
```

I never see something in the console.log

Answer (score 0):

you can use same `componentWillUnmount` to do that as well

```
componentWillUnmount() {
          AsyncStorage.removeItem('item');
          AppState.removeEventListener('change', this.handleAppStateChange);
 }
```

assuming this file is root js file and will unmount only when app closed

Comment: setitem of storage is in another screen

Comment: if i use componentWillUnmount in the screen where setitem is , it works

Comment: but i dont want this behavior, but it makes no sense for storing item, it will be removed on navigation

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `AppState` for this Use Case. You can remove the AsyncStorage Item in `componentWillUnmount`.

```
componentWillUnmount() {
    AsyncStorage.removeItem('item');
}
```

Comment: yes i tried this but when navigating between screens it removes the storage, which i dont want, I want to remove the storage only when closing the app